# Alpine Image standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Tags: c++, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to run an alpine based container which will run a hello world C++ program on starting. However, I'm getting a 
`standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"` error on running the container.

I did an `ls -al` into the container to check if the file exists with the correct permissions. The executable(named `test`) exists in the root directory with `-rwxrwxr-x` permissions.

This is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM alpine:latest
ADD test /
ENTRYPOINT ["/test"]
```

Can someone help me in identifying what the issue is? Thanks !

Edit : I compiled my .cpp file on Ubuntu 18.04 to generate the executable.
`g++ -o test test.cpp`

test.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `test`? How did you create it? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Sorry, I've added an edit to reproduce the error. Please have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably because you build out `test` binary on non-alpine operation system, and then try to run it in alpine.

E.g. If you check the dependency of your binary, you may could find next(this could be different according to your system):

```
$ ldd test
linux-vdso.so.1
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

But in alpine, it do not use glibc, it use [musl libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/).

So suggest you directly build it out in alpine, or for simple application, use next:

```
g++ -o test -static test.cpp
```